# Django-Elasticsearch-DSL Nested Range Query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm trying to implement the following Elasticsearch query using django-elasticsearch-dsl and am having some difficulty

**Query**

```
  {
   "query":{
      "nested":{
         "path":"ip_addresses",
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "filter":[
                  {
                     "range":{
                        "ip_addresses.ip":{
                           "gte":"192.168.1.0",
                           "lte":"192.168.1.255"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Code**

```
  def search_ip_range(self, start: str, end: str):
        range_query = Q('range', gte=start, lte=end)

        search = Search()
        search = search.query('nested', path='ip_addresses', query=range_query)

        try:
            response = search.execute()
            pprint("Found {} results".format(response.hits.total.value))

            for hit in response:
                pprint(hit.detail_url)
        except Exception as e:
            pprint('Search error: {}'.format(e))
```

**Error**

```
RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[range] query does not support [gte]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the author of `elasticsearch-dsl-py` says, [you'll need to use nested filters](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/304#issuecomment-161004015). One option would be:

```
...

range_query = Q('range', ip_addresses__ip={'gte': start, 'lte': end})

search = Search()
search = search.query('nested', path='ip_addresses', query=Q('bool', filter=[range_query]))

pprint(search.to_dict())

...
```

You can leave out the `Q(bool, filter=` part but the `range` won't then be wrapped in the it:

```
search = search.query('nested', path='ip_addresses', query=range_query)
```

Keep in mind that if you **do** wrap it in the `filter` context, [no scores will be calculated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context).